# ASP.Net Core Database deploy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I want to deploy my app on IIS+Postgres (dnx 7.0.0-rc1-16348). I copied deploy files, set up IIS, on the part of web server everything seems to work fine. Problem is the database. I had a pair of migrations in my `/Migration` folder. I run `ef` from command line, it works fine (the unicorn appears), correctly detects context class in my app... I'm sure the connection string to database is correct, postgres post is open. But `ef database update` doesn't work. I created `__EFMigrationsHistory` manually. I removed all migrations from app and ran `ef migrations add`. EF throws `InvalidCastException` in all cases. On development machine everything works fine. Have I missed something while deploing?

**SOLVED**
I only updated npgsql driver for EF7